# stop first sound when second is playing

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am an absolute beginner in both objective-c and other environments so please be patient. Here is my problem: I need to play sound files so that each of them stops when the other is started, right now they overlap; here is a snippet of my code.
Thank you in advance and let me know if you need other details.

```
- (IBAction)soundfirst {
    NSString *path =
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"hi2" ofType:@"mp3"];

    player1 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
        initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]
                        error:NULL];

    player1.delegate = self;
    [player1 play];
}
- (IBAction)soundsecond {
    [player1 stop];

    NSString *path =
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"hi2" ofType:@"mp3"];

    player2 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
        initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]
                        error:NULL];

    player2.delegate = self;
    [player2 play];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do something when you're stuck, is to look into the documentation.

In your code, you're creating an object of type AVAudioPlayer, and naming it player1.

AVAudioPlayer Documentation:
*http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html*

look under the **instance methods**, and there's a method there called stop.

So in the first method, you can do something like

```
if(player2.playing){
    [player2 stop];
}

[player1 play];
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try and see if it works. Thank you nonetheless.

Comment: Hi again Khanh, sorry to disturb you but i have a new problem now: yesterday your solution worked but I wanted to make the code more simple and less cluttered. So now I have this problem when I try to use the " if ": use of undeclared identifier "playsound2 ". Where can I post the code without generating a new question ? Thank you in advance. N.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>

SystemSoundID buttonClickSoundID;

+ (void)playButtonClickSound {
    if (buttonClickSoundID == 0) {
        NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"button_click" ofType:@"wav"];
        CFURLRef soundURL = (CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundURL, &buttonClickSoundID);
    }
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(buttonClickSoundID);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Anton I seem to have solved it now. Have a good day /night